# Pandas sum over a date range for each category separately

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, grouping, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with timeseries of sales transactions for different items:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_3 = pd.DataFrame()

# Create datetimes and data
df_1['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='D')
df_1['item'] = 1
df_1['sales']= 2

df_2['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='D')
df_2['item'] = 2
df_2['sales']= 3

df_3['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='D')
df_3['item'] = 3
df_3['sales']= 4

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3])
df = df.sort_values(['item'])
df
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    date    item    sales
0   2018-01-01  1   2
1   2018-01-02  1   2
2   2018-01-03  1   2
3   2018-01-04  1   2
4   2018-01-05  1   2
0   2018-01-01  2   3
1   2018-01-02  2   3
2   2018-01-03  2   3
3   2018-01-04  2   3
4   2018-01-05  2   3
0   2018-01-01  3   4
1   2018-01-02  3   4
2   2018-01-03  3   4
3   2018-01-04  3   4
4   2018-01-05  3   4
```

I want to compute a sum of "sales" for a given item in a given time window. I can't use pandas rolling.sum
because the timeseries is sparse (eg. 2018-01-01 > 2018-01-04 > 2018-01-06 > etc.).

I've tried this solution (for time window = 2 days):

```
df['start_date'] = df['date'] - timedelta(3)
df['end_date'] = df['date'] - timedelta(1)
df['rolled_sales'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df.date >= x.start_date) & 
                                            (df.date <= x.end_date), 'sales'].sum(), axis=1)
```

but it results with sums of sales of all items for a given time window:

```
    date    item    sales   start_date  end_date    rolled_sales
0   2018-01-01  1   2   2017-12-29  2017-12-31  0
1   2018-01-02  1   2   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  9
2   2018-01-03  1   2   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  18
3   2018-01-04  1   2   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  27
4   2018-01-05  1   2   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  27
0   2018-01-01  2   3   2017-12-29  2017-12-31  0
1   2018-01-02  2   3   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  9
2   2018-01-03  2   3   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  18
3   2018-01-04  2   3   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  27
4   2018-01-05  2   3   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  27
0   2018-01-01  3   4   2017-12-29  2017-12-31  0
1   2018-01-02  3   4   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  9
2   2018-01-03  3   4   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  18
3   2018-01-04  3   4   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  27
4   2018-01-05  3   4   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  27
```

My goal is to have rolled_sales computed for each item separately, like this:

```
    date    item    sales   start_date  end_date    rolled_sales
0   2018-01-01  1   2   2017-12-29  2017-12-31  0
1   2018-01-02  1   2   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  2
2   2018-01-03  1   2   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  4
3   2018-01-04  1   2   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  6
4   2018-01-05  1   2   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  8
0   2018-01-01  2   3   2017-12-29  2017-12-31  0
1   2018-01-02  2   3   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  3
2   2018-01-03  2   3   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  6
3   2018-01-04  2   3   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  9
4   2018-01-05  2   3   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  12
0   2018-01-01  3   4   2017-12-29  2017-12-31  0
1   2018-01-02  3   4   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  4
2   2018-01-03  3   4   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  8
3   2018-01-04  3   4   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  12
4   2018-01-05  3   4   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  16
```

I tried to apply solution suggested here: [Pandas rolling sum for multiply values separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510308/pandas-rolling-sum-for-multiply-values-separately)
but failed.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks in advance :)

Andy

Comment: `df.groupby('item').rolling('2D', on='date').sales.sum()` does not work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. Many thanks :) Andy

Answer (score 1):

Total sales With **2-days** rolling window per item:

```
z = df.sort_values('date').set_index('date').groupby('item').rolling('2d')['sales'].sum()
```

Output:

```
item  date      
1     2018-01-01    2.0
      2018-01-02    4.0
      2018-01-03    4.0
      2018-01-04    4.0
      2018-01-05    4.0
2     2018-01-01    3.0
      2018-01-02    6.0
      2018-01-03    6.0
      2018-01-04    6.0
      2018-01-05    6.0
3     2018-01-01    4.0
      2018-01-02    8.0
      2018-01-03    8.0
      2018-01-04    8.0
      2018-01-05    8.0
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```

Total sales from last 2 days per item:

```
df[df.groupby('item').cumcount() < 2 ].groupby('item').sum()
```

Total sales between start_date and end_date per item:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-2')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-12-2')
df[df['date'].between(start_date, end_date)].groupby('item')['sales'].sum()
```

Comment: nope :(. I don't want to have fixed dates, but rolling window of a given size (7 days in my case). General idea is to compute, for each item and a given date, total sales from previous 7 days.

Comment: I've updated answer, but if it still not match, please provide full example of output.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['rolled_sum'] = (df.groupby('item')
                    .rolling('3D', on='date').sum()['sales']
                    .to_numpy()
                  )
```

After some data wrangling (I removed some rows to simulate sparse dates, and added helper columns "start_date" and "end_date" for 3 days distance from a given date), the final output looks like this:

```
    date    item    sales   start_date  end_date    rolled_sum
0   2018-01-01  1   2   2017-12-30  2018-01-01  2.0
3   2018-01-04  1   2   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  2.0
4   2018-01-05  1   2   2018-01-03  2018-01-05  4.0
7   2018-01-08  1   2   2018-01-06  2018-01-08  2.0
9   2018-01-10  1   2   2018-01-08  2018-01-10  4.0
12  2018-01-03  2   3   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  3.0
13  2018-01-04  2   3   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  6.0
15  2018-01-06  2   3   2018-01-04  2018-01-06  6.0
17  2018-01-08  2   3   2018-01-06  2018-01-08  6.0
18  2018-01-09  2   3   2018-01-07  2018-01-09  6.0
19  2018-01-10  2   3   2018-01-08  2018-01-10  9.0
21  2018-01-02  3   4   2017-12-31  2018-01-02  4.0
23  2018-01-04  3   4   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  8.0
25  2018-01-06  3   4   2018-01-04  2018-01-06  8.0
26  2018-01-07  3   4   2018-01-05  2018-01-07  8.0
27  2018-01-08  3   4   2018-01-06  2018-01-08  12.0
28  2018-01-09  3   4   2018-01-07  2018-01-09  12.0
29  2018-01-10  3   4   2018-01-08  2018-01-10  12.0
```

The magic was in rolling.sum parameter: instead of "3", I should use "3D".

Many Thanks for Your help :)

Andy